# Django Admin Site two model combine into 1 model using foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have this table StudentProfile

[image: StudentProfile]

and table StudentEnrollmentRecord, I just want to add an column before the Student User just like the picture below,

[image]

this is my code in model.py

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
   LRN = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
   Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)

class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
```

and this is my code in admin.py

```
class StudentsEnrollmentRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Student_Users', 'School_Year', 'Courses', 'Section', 'Payment_Type', 'Education_Levels')
    ordering = ('Education_Levels',)
    list_filter = ('Education_Levels','Section','Student_Users')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define a separate function in your Admin class to retrieve the column from your related object:

```py
class StudentsEnrollmentRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def lrn(self, obj):
        return obj.Student_Users.lrn
```

and then use it in `list_display`

```py
list_display = ('lrn', ...)
```

I also recommend using `list_select_related` so it doesn't query DB for every row.

```py
class StudentsEnrollmentRecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_select_related = ('Student_Users')
```

Comment: i got this error """type object 'StudentsEnrollmentRecord' has no attribute 'Student_Users__LRN'""

Comment: hmm that's strange, it should work. I wonder if it has anything to do with you using capital letters for model fields (which goes against the standard practice)

Comment: do you have any idea to fix this sir?

Comment: I'm not sure yet - What Django version are you using? Can you show `list_display` from your `StudentProfileAdmin`?

Comment: list_display = ('lrn','Firstname', 'Middle_Initial', 'Lastname', 'Request') the django version i used is 2.2.4

Comment: I realized my mistake and updated my answer @marvin - `__field` relations don't work in Admin.fields/list_fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201447/discussion-between-marvin-and-radoh).